# javascript pattern : referencing "this" inside private and public functions

Tags: design-patterns, javascript

i've search on other questions, and their "this" question is not really similar. also googling, but not really understand.

where is `this` referrencing to? As quirksmode said

> ..this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing,
>   or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.

For newbie like me, it's still confusing. The code is:

```
var Yourlib = (function() {
    var elementSelected = [],
    totalElement = 0;

    function yourQSA(str) {
        elementSelected = document.querySelectorAll(str);
        totalElement = elementSelected.length;

        return this // this#1 , where is "THIS" referencing to??
    }

    return {
        byClass : function(str) {
            elementSelected = document.getElementsByClassName(str);
            totalElement = elementSelected.length;

            return this; // this#2, the "THIS" is referencing to "Yourlib" obj
        },
        qsa : yourQSA,
        setColor: function(clr) {
            var n = 0;
            for ( ; n < totalElement; n++ ) {
                elementSelected[n].style.color = clr;
            }

            return this;
        }
    }

}());
```

Question: Where is the this#1 referencing to? Or is it just better to write `return Yourlib;` instead of `return this;`? (we want to chain the methods)

Thank You

*note, the goal si to create chaining method. something like `Yourlib.byClass('yourclass').setColor('#ff0000');`

Comment: The `this` in a function is dependent on how/where the function is called. Since we don't see how/where the function is called we can't really say

Comment: @Musa when we want to chain the methods, i mean, `Yourlib.byClass('yourclass').setColor('#ff0000');` , the this #2 works fine. how about this #1?

Comment: It will be the same, did you try it?

Comment: @Musa : I ever try the this#2, and works. But do not know about this#1

Comment: Why don't you show the full code, how do you call qsa etc...

Comment: From your code `Yourlib.qsa` is the global object (i.e. `window`)

Comment: `qsa : yourQSA(),` should be `qsa : yourQSA,` and then it should work exactly like `byClass ` and `setColor`

Comment: @Musa : Whoaa you are true sir! So the `this` on qsa refers to global object (i.e. window) ? *Thank you for correction.

Comment: You keep changing the code in your post, when you do `qsa : yourQSA()` `this` is will be `window`

Comment: @Musa : Now the code is changed to qsa: yourQSA . So the summary, the both of `this` is referencing the same obj? Please write an answer, i will make it accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this#1` and `this#2` will be the same object once both functions are called as methods of the object

```
Yourlib.byClass('yourclass').setColor('#ff0000');
Yourlib.qsa('.yourclass').setColor('#ff0000');
```

note if you do something like

```
var qsa = Yourlib.qsa;
qsa('.yourclass').setColor('#ff0000');
```

its not going to work since you aren't calling the function as a method of the object.

You could also use functions like [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set `this` (the context) in a function

```
var qsa = Yourlib.qsa;
qsa.call(Yourlib, '.yourclass').setColor('#ff0000');
qsa.apply(Yourlib, ['.yourclass']).setColor('#ff0000');
(qsa.bind(Yourlib))('.yourclass').setColor('#ff0000');
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` references the object the current method is attached to, because every object has two things:

- properties
- and methods

[this keyword](http://www.whiterootmedia.com/database/dusty_arlia/this_keyword.html)

Comment: How about this case? when we want to chain the methods, i mean, `Yourlib.byClass('yourclass').setColor('#ff0000');` , the this #2 works fine. how about this #1?
or it is just better to write return Yourlib instead of return this?

Answer (score 0):

`this` #1 is referencing to the object of type Yourlib, i.e. it's "instance".

`this` #2 is referencing to an anonymous object which is returned by `return { .... }`

The concept is like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MqqHY/

You might alter that, but basically, I think there are some flaws in your object code, since

```
var Yourlib = (function() {
...
}());
```

means you're immediately executing this instead of just only defining a new Class?

Comment: when we want to chain the methods, i mean, `Yourlib.byClass('yourclass').setColor('#ff0000');` , the this #2 works fine. how about this #1?

Comment: In this specific example, I'd believe that you're mistaken.  The function declaration is only referenced by the object literal, so wouldn't `this` refer to the same item?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy : The `this` on this#2 works. this#2 is what people teach on the web. But, im confused about the this#1 . Will it works?

Comment: @Axel Amthor : the use is like

`var yourElm = Yourlib.byClass('yourclass');`
`yourElm.chained1().chained2();`

Comment: added this to my jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/MqqHY/ above and this gives: `TypeError: yourElm.chained1 is not a function`.

Comment: @AxelAmthor : the codes on the post were updated. i show new codes.
`Yourlib.byClass('yourclass').setColor('#f00'); // works` .
But don't know about `Yourlib.qsa('myclass').setColor('#00f');`

Comment: @BagusJavas queryselector uses css selectors so use `Yourlib.qsa('.myclass').setColor('#00f');`

Comment: @Musa : Thank you for correction, so `this` on qsa is just the same with `this` on byClass & setColor? i just try it, and both of `this` works fine. Please post and answer, so i can close the question